# What does it mean グレード・オプション?

Tags: words

Full text:

> グレード・オプション装備により記録されるデータ項目は異なります。な お、コンピューターは会話などの音声や車内の映像は記録しません。

My understanding: The data items recorded will vary depending on the grade and optional equipment. Please note, the computer does not record any audio or in-car video footage of the conversations.

My Issue: グレード・オプション. Is it grade and optional equipment or grade option equipment? How do we translate the ・?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "・"symbol is used as a space between two words. Japanese doesn't normally use spaces, but the foreign words being used might confuse a Japanese reader, so the space helps the reader realise that there are two separate words: grade and option.

From the context, I assume that this car(?) comes in different grades, which have different specifications. On top of that, a buyer can choose different options within a grade. So the data recording will depend on both the grade (of vehicle) and the optional equipment.

Comment: Yes, the Japanese texts are from a car manual. Thank you for helping me understand.

Answer (score 2):

Unless "grade option" has a specific meaning in your context, this `・` symbol is just "and" or "or". It's interchangeable with や. Your translation seems fine to me.

Comment: Yes, It seems that ・ here is "and". Thank you.